# django router forgets the DB while pointing to ForeignKey

Tags: mysql, django, database, dynamic, router

My mobileapp is going to be used by different schools( with different db but same structure).Logged in user(parent) will be connected with multiple db(if their two child in different schools) using DynamicDbRouter. Now the problem is django router forgets the DB while pointing to ForeignKey.

views.py

```
    class StudentFees(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):
        template_name = 'student_fees.html'
        def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(StudentFees,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        schl_id=kwargs['schl_id']
        school_id=School.objects.get(id=kwargs['schl_id'])
        with in_database(school_id) :
            context['classes'] = StudentSection.objects.filter(student_detail=kwargs['student_id'])
            context['invoices'] = Invoice.objects.filter(student_master=kwargs['student_id'],status=1)
            print context
        return context
```

Here student_detail & student_master are foreign key fields.

routers.py

```
    class in_database(object):
        def __init__(self, client, read=True, write=False):
        ...
        database = {'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql','NAME':client.db_name,'USER':client.username,'PASSWORD':client.password,'HOST':client.host,'PORT':client.port}       
        ...
```

Instead of pointing to client_db.model it points to default_db.model while accessing foreign keys.
I can able to see context details in console.. but values not redering in student_fees.html. It throws error like
ProgrammingError :
default_db.studentsection' doesn't exist

Comment: It not like situation of foreign key across different databases. but within same database.both invoice and student master are different table in same database only

Comment: so then what is the problem??

Comment: context details are printing in console window.. but values not redering in student_fees.html